# Domain filter in purchase order line Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to filter products in purchase order line based on value in parent table (purchase.order).

**Purchase_order.py**

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'purchase.order'
   product_variety_type = fields.Selection([('raw_material','Raw Material'),('stationary','Stationary')],string='Product Variety')
```

I already defined a domain filter in `purchase.order.line`.py, need to add one more condition `('variety','=',self._context.get('variety')`

```py
 class PurchaseOrderLines(models.Model):
_inherit = 'purchase.order.line'


@api.onchange('product_id')
@api.depends('order_id')
def onchange_product_id2(self):

    product_variety_type = self._context.get('variety') // Value is None
    result = super(PurchaseOrderLines,self).onchange_product_id()
    supplier_infos = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('name', '=', self.partner_id.id)])
    product_ids = self.env['product.product']
    if not supplier_infos:
        product_ids = product_ids.search([])
    for supplier_info in supplier_infos:
         product_ids += supplier_info.product_tmpl_id.product_variant_ids

    result.update({'domain': {'product_id': [('id', 'in', product_ids.ids)]}})

    return result
```

I tried to pass a context value from parent view,but no luck.

***.xml**

```xml
  <field name="partner_id" position="after">
        <field name="product_variety_type" required="1" context="
        {'variety':product_variety_type}"/>

  </field>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: I've just experimented the same on v10, I added a context to a standard button and the called method isn't receiving my context. This worked for sure on previous versions. May be only if the `onchange` parameter was in the XML? Just in case, remove the `@api.depends` from your onchange method and try it again.

Comment: Try fetching the context like `self.env.context.get(key)`

Comment: Shouldn't be the context on the line (product_id) be set? Like `context="{'variety': parent.product_variety_type}"`.

Comment: @CZoellner, i tried that. but context update only after execution of on_change method.

Comment: And what about `product_variety_type = self.order_id.product_variety_type` or `product_variety_type = self._origin.order_id.product_variety_type` ?

Comment: @CZoellner, `product_variety_type = self.order_id.product_variety_type`, it worked for me. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the `context`. Just use `self.order_id` to get the value.

```py
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id2(self):
    product_variety_type = self.order_id.product_variety_type
    # and so on
```